# AC MOSFET Switch

Tags: mosfet, switches, ac, frequency

I'm trying to use MOSFETs to allow or block 450kHz sine wave. Here's the test circuit:
[image: AC MOSFET SWITCH]

At low frequency, MOSFETS are totally able to switch on and off. But when the frequency becomes higher at 450kHz, it seems MOSFETS are not able to block sine wave anymore, no matter if apply or not 5V-signal at OPT_SIG: oscilloscope always shows sine wave on load (R1).

I tried with other parts such as FDP020N06B with very low rds but I get the same result.

I've also found older MOSFETs STP5NB40FP and using them, RMS voltage on load is almost 0, when signal is not applied. 
I was thinking the high frequency AC to be passing through MOSFET capacitance Cds, but both FDP020N06B (Coss = 3840pF) and IPD60R180P7S (Coss = 19pF) behave the same way.

STP5NB40FP MOSFET has lower continuous drain current and much higher Rds resistance compared to the previous ones. I'd like to choose MOSFET with Rds as low as possible but work as well.
So it'll be another characteristic I'm not taking into account. Could you please help me?

I got some screens from my oscilloscope as a clear evidence of that. Blue track is the input sine, yellow track is the signal on the load. You can see the big differences between them. R9 was replaced with a short.
[SCREEN](https://postimg.cc/xNnTHgDN)

Datasheets: [IPD60R180P7S](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPD60R180P7S-DS-v02_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625cc9456a015d55249fca0f9c), [FDP020N06B](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDP020N06B-D.pdf), [STP5NB40FP](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/ST%20Microelectronics%20PDFS/STP5NB40_FP.pdf)

Comment: Look at the voltage across R9. I think you're going to find a lot of 450 kHz there, due to Cgd. You're going to need to actively clamp the gates to ground when the transistors are supposed to be off.

Comment: What happens, if you short circuit the R9 (with disabled 12V_iso, of course)?

Comment: Please provide a link to the pdf datasheet on the STM website for the STP5NB40FP

Comment: I did very similar almost 20 years ago. I used a floating supply for the gate drive and then added a shorting FET at the output to further increase isolation. I was switching maybe 100 Watts in an inductive power transfer circuit and applying on/off control to create signalling slots for comms over the loop. The power levels were such that leakage through the MOSFETs was too high. The extra clamp fixed it nicely.

Comment: @DaveTweed Shorting R9 to ground makes no difference. Sine wave is always on the load.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič  Basically, it makes no difference. Sine wave is always on the load.

Comment: @Andyaka [datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/5321.pdf)

Comment: I said earlier: *Please provide a link to the pdf datasheet on the STM website for the STP5NB40FP* and you have not done that.

Comment: @Andyaka If you look to my previous comment I posted a link to a datasheet. It's not from STM website, cause I'm not able to find that part on their website

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Can you please give me an example of this extra clamp? But why using STP5NB40FP the circuit is working?

Comment: @Andyaka [this](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/ST%20Microelectronics%20PDFS/STP5NB40_FP.pdf) might be the best you're going to get in that regard; the part seems to be obsolete enough that ST doesn't have it on their website anymore.

Comment: Presumably you have links to all the datasheets for the parts you mention. Please put any information in the question. Putting "datasheet" in a comment where it needs to be searched out with care and luck and no clue as to which of the several FETs it refers to is not adequate. Capacitances, Rdson. Vgdsth, ... all MAY play a part. Helping us help you helps.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I edited my question, so now link to datasheets are available

Comment: @kristian_  In your case the extra clamp is a FET across R1 which is turned on when Q3+ Q4 are turned off. This may also have been a back to back pair in my application.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon By doing so, this would mean shorting ac signal if MOSFETs let the ac sine pass through with small resistance

Comment: @kristian_ Yes indeeed. If the series MOSFETS do not do their job the parallel shunt will do it for them. When you say that some MOSFETS "do not work" you presumably mean " .... well enough". ie they are partially on. If they are on by a significant amount the dissipated energy in the series part may be excessive. There is a limit to any design. What voltage do you see on the load when the series FETS are off? || Have you tried a fully floating supply - a 9V battery may be enough fo testing) for the series MOSFET gate supply?

Answer (score 1):

> *So it'll be another characteristic I'm not taking into account. Could
>   you please help me?*

Well, it's the right characteristic you are considering but you need to dig into the detail of the what you say here: -

> *IPD60R180P7S (Coss = 19pF)*

The truth is, if you compare apples with apples, the \$C_{OSS}\$ of this device is more like 250 pF. The apples are the drain source voltage. See graph below: -

[image]

At an applied drain source voltage of 25 volts, the IPD60R180P7S has a capacitance of 250 pF (not 19 pF as said on the salesman designed front sheet).

As for the STP5NB40FP (data sheet link kindly supplied by @Hearth), the \$C_{OSS}\$ is 72 pF when \$V_{DS}\$ is 25 volts: -

[image]

In other words, the STM device is better hence it produces less residual output voltage when the SSR (solid state relay) is off.

Comment: Ok, the explanation is clear. But in these graphs, VDS is assumed to be continuous and not time-varying. Am I wrong? What could it be the real Coss with a 100V RMS sine wave on the drain? And as well, I'm not applying sine wave directly to its VDS. I made two tests with both STP and IPD part: 1.applying 87V RMS sine wave,  2. applying 19V RMS. Blue track is input sine, yellow track is output signal on the load. 
[test](https://i.postimg.cc/nrQsyw32/TEST.jpg). 
Having to choose the right MOSFETs, shoud I find a part with Coss as low and constant over VDS as possible? Thanks

Comment: VDS is constant but modulated with a small test AC signal in order to measure capacitance. A big AC signal means a significant change in capacitance over each cycle but, the message is clear. Choose the MOSFET with the lowest capacitance in the same signal conditions but, choose a MOSFET that can handle the maximum AC voltage you wish to supply.

Comment: I’m not going to analyse remote screenshots of waveforms. I’ve made my answer. If you don’t understand it raise a comment. If you want to add a whole pile of other stuff, raise a brand new question.

Comment: I'll try to find other MOSFETs with the highlighted characteristics. The screen test I uploaded was just a clear evidence of the results i found. I'll add it in the main question

Comment: Please don’t move the goalposts by changing the focus of the original question. If something hasn’t been addressed from the original question in my answer, please focus on that. This is a question and answer site and not a forum or training school. Hope you understand.

Comment: I'm not changing anything. I've just enriched my question with a clear evidence of what is happening. I was looking for a relationship between output voltage on load and MOSFETs Coss explaining the real behaviour.

Comment: Those screen shots explain nothing that I can understand. They relate to what nodes on what circuit? Think about it in terms of a reader of your question and what they might mean to someone who doesn’t know where you connected the scope probes to (like me). In other words, what story are they telling?

Comment: If you read my previous comment over again, you'll find all the information. I said blue track is the sine input, i.e. 450kHz sine in the schematic (frequency clearly present in the sceen). Yellow track is the output signal on load (this could only be the only unclear point: R1 is the load on schematic)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use a specific ic to drive the mosfet, it could be more fast. Look at datasheet of "**mcp1407 driver mosfet**".

Comment: can you please expand this answer? This looks like a comment, not an answer. Thanks